# Google Chrome saying cannot read property "calculator" of undefined - Calculator is function name

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am relatively new to JavaScript, so I am making a simple calculator to get my use to how it works.

Chrome is spitting out an error saying, "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'calculator' of undefined". I am bewildered by what is wrong with my function name.

Here's my Javascript:

```
function calculate(){
            var one = document.container.calculator.one.value;
            var two = document.container.calculator.two.value;
            var three = "";

            //Grab the textfield to update with calculation
            var calcField = document.getElementById("calculated");

            // Let's do the math
            three = one*two;

            //Update the textfield
            if(!empty(three)){
                calcField.innerHTML = three;
            }
        }
```

The HTML:

```
<div id="container">
        <form id="calculator">
            Value 1: <input type="text" name="one" id="one" onChange="calculate();"><br />
            Value 2: <input type="text" name="two" id="two" onChange="calculate();">
            <br /><br />Calculated Text<br />
            <input type="text" id="calculated" name="calculated" readonly>
        </form>
    </div>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace

```
document.container.calculator.one
```

with

```
document.getElementById("one")
```

Comment: Question, it is now saying that calculate is undefined.. Any ideas? @JamesMontagne